# Restore Spacemacs project windows layouts

Tags: spacemacs, projectile, window-splitting

Opening a project I would like the windows restored as I left them. E.g.
`tests.py` on the left and a terminal `/home/projectdir/>$` on the right:

```
|-----------+-----------|
| tests.py  | >$_       |
|           |           |
|-----------+-----------|
```

However, after restarting emacs, followed by `Spc p l` [Helm switch project
layout] and selecting the project, **none of my set Window is restored** but all
I'm asked is to open a file from the projectfolder. Furthermore I see the layout's (project) name in the modeline.